# Как получить доступ ко всем свойствам объекта, не используя «отражение» c#

Tags: c#, рефлексия

делаю маппер из одного класса в другой, как я могу получить все свойства объекта не прибегая к отражению, для того чтобы их обработать и преобразовать в другой класс

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы всё маппилось "само", то никак

Comment: В рантайме — кроме рефлексии никак

Comment: Мне советовали использовать дерево выражений, но я не понял что имели ввиду

Comment: Чем вас AutoMapper не устраивает?

Comment: @Kirya522, чтобы построить дерево выражений все равно потребуется рефлексия